# Xdamage unable to get damage region

Tags: c++, c, x11, xorg, xcb

```
Display *display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
Window root = XDefaultRootWindow(display);

int damage_event, damage_error, count = 0;

XDamageQueryExtension(display, &damage_event, &damage_error);
//tried all 4  damage levels giving the same output
Damage dmg = XDamageCreate(display, root, XDamageReportNonEmpty); 
XDamageNotifyEvent *dmg_ev = NULL;
XEvent event;
while (1)
{

    XNextEvent(display, &event);

    if (event.type == damage_event + XDamageNotify)
    {
        printf("Got event\n");
        dmg_ev = (XDamageNotifyEvent *)&event;
        auto region = XFixesCreateRegion(display, NULL, 0);
        XDamageSubtract(display, dmg_ev->damage, None, region);
        auto area = XFixesFetchRegion(display, region, &count);
        if (area)
        {
            printf("count is %d \n", count);
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                auto rect = area[i];
                printf("x:%d y:%d height:%d width:%d\n", rect.x, rect.y, rect.height, rect.width);
            }
            XFree(area);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("areaa is NULL \n");
        }
        XFixesDestroyRegion(display, region);
    }
}
```

https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/damageproto/damageproto.txt

I am using Xdamage to detect changes in my screen or like the specific region where the change occurred ..like if I made a change inside a text editor at say row 30 and col 40 I need to isolate out that specific region alone. The above program is running but is always giving the output as

x:0 y:0 height:1080 width:1920)(which is my screen resolution)

Could someone tell me if I am missing something or if it's possible or not to get the exact region where the changes occurred using Xdamage or if there is there some other library that I could use (Taking a screenshot and comparing it with the previous image is a possible solution but it drains a lot of CPU.. need something that takes less CPU)?

Comment: What desktop environment / window manager are you using? I would guess that "something with GL" could very well look to the X11 server as page flips, i.e. the whole image is replaced. I would guess that you might have more look by watching individual windows for changes rather than "everything".

Comment: I am using Kubuntu 20,04 (Kwin)...

Comment: Yup, that will definitely use "something like OpenGL" for the drawing.

Answer (score 0):

From *damageproto.txt*:

> **6. DamageReportLevel**
>
> DamageReportNonEmpty
>
> Delivers a single DamageNotify event each time the damage rectangle changes from empty to non-empty, and also whenever the result of a DamageSubtract request results in a non-empty region.

From that, it shouldn't be a surprise, that you're receiving only one event reporting the size of the root window (either first time drawn or if there are no more damaged areas).

Instead, use `DamageReportRawRectangles` or `DamageReportDeltaRectangles` as `DamageReportLevel` in the function call to `XDamageCreate`. `DamageReportDeltaRectangles` is probably the better choice, since it avoids being flooded with `DamageNotifyEvents`.

Further

> **3.1 Additions in the 1.1 version of the protocol**
>
> ... but direct rendering extensions have allowed clients to perform rendering outside of the control of the X Server.

So, it is possible that not all areas will be reported (if at all). Either the used extensions or toolkits provides an interface to get the damaged areas or otherwise some lib would have to take a screenshot and take the difference of the previous one and calculate the damaged regions on a per pixel basis. Not the most performant way.

Comment: i already tried all the different DamageReportLevel's (DamageReportRawRectangles, DamageReportDeltaRectangles, and others) but they produce similar output...

Comment: Then could we conclude, that the window/composite manager does not report damages? Further, could the rectangle you receive be the result of a full window redraw? If the composite manager redirects the paints into a pixmap, then this could be it. What bothers me, is the fact, that `XDamageSubtract` sets `region` to `damage` and empties the `damage`, since the `repair` argument is set to `None`.